# How to fetch discord member list

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to fetch the member list of a discord server. The Discord bot is inside the server and has admin permission. I'm referring to this part of the documentation [Discord Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#list-guild-members).

```
const response = await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/685509789178003502/members`, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bot ${botToken}`
            }
        })
var currentUser = await response.json()
```

This is the response I'm getting
`{"message":"Missing Access","code":50001}`
I checked it like a million times and the bot has admin perms 100%.

Comment: Do you have members intent enabled and configured?

Comment: @3nws thank you very much. it was this little step i had overseen. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `Members Intent`

*Further Reading: https://gist.github.com/advaith1/e69bcc1cdd6d0087322734451f15aa2f*